# docker-compose tries to pull already existing images

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerhub

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file, which defines a services and its image.

```
service:
    image: my_image
```

now, that I run `docker-compose up` I get the following message:

```
$ docker-compose up    
Pulling service (my_image:latest)...
Pulling repository docker.io/library/my_image
ERROR: Error: image library/my_image:latest not found
```

It is correct, that `my_image` in this case is not on the docker hub. But I've created it with `docker build -t my_image .` (in a different file) before and it is listed in `docker images`.

Is there anything I miss to tell docker-compose, to not look for the image in the docker.io registry/hub?

[edit] docker client and server version is `1.9.1`, docker-compose version is `1.5.2`.

I'm running docker-compose (as well as docker) through the HTTP-API on a remote machine, don't know if this makes any difference.

Comment: I just tried this and it works. I used different folders for `Dockerfile` and for `docker-compose.yml`. Are you sure about the image name? What version of docker are you using? I'm using 1.9 and it works. If you are using a prior version, maybe you need to include the version too

Comment: if you try to run an image that doesn't exist it will try to pull it. I think you probably have a typo somewhere that is causing it to try and pull a different image.

Comment: I have verified the spelling and even tried it with and without adding the tag `my_image:latest`, it made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you have image local or anywhere except docker hub you need to use **build** and path or url to Dockerfile. So basically when we work OFF dockerhub we change image to path !

```
ubuntu:
  container_name: ubuntu
  build: /compose/build/ubuntu
  links:
    - db:mysql
  ports:
    - 80:80
```

In this example am using my own Ubuntu Dockerfile that is places in the build path. The file should be named Dockerfile like normal and you just specify the path to folder where it is.

Comment: The creation of the images is happening in a different location. I'm running the docker-compose command through the remote-api and hoped to just “re-use” the images, already created on the host. Is ther no way of achieving this, than running the `docker run` command manually?